# Algorithm to allocate optimal toilet room

Tags: algorithm, heapsort, binary-heap

Given toilets from 1 to n. A person can make reservation in toilet and use it for certain interval.Allocate Toilets for incoming reservation according to below rules.

1. Assign toilets which is at maximum distance from other toilet currently in used (example: For 1 to 9 toilet , if 1 and 9 are occupied then allocate 5 to next reservation request).
2. If for two toilets maximum difference is same then allocate left most i.e. whose index is less.(Example for case: 1 to 9 toilets, currently in used are 1,9,5 then for next reservation allocate 3)

For a given incoming reservation and leaving sequence find the sum of all serial numbers of toilet that are assigned.

Input:
First line T- No of test case(1<=T<=10)
N number of toilets, M requests(1<=N,M<=20,000)
M line follows two integer 
A for request type incoming/outgoing reservation, B Person Id of person who made the reservation (if A==1 then incoming reservation, A==2 leaving after using the toilet)
(1<=A<=2, 1<=B<=999999)

Sample Input:
1
5 7
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
1 1
1 5
Output: 16
Explanation: N = 5, M = 7. Person Id 1 assigned to toilet no.1, person id-2 assigned to toilet no.5, person id 3 to toilet no. 3, person id 4 to   2 , then person id 1 left the toilet then person id 1 again made reservation and assigned 1 and person Id 5 was assigned 4.
so final answer is 1+5+3+2+1+4=16.

My approach to this problem is: Created a max heap of (startRange,endRange,Distance) and pop out the maximum distance value from heap.

```
if(startRange==1 || endRange==n) {
assignned accordingly
}else{
toilet no is avg = (startRange+endRange)/2
and pushed (startRange,avg-1,distance) and (avg+1,endRange,distance) into our heap
}
```

Now problem is if some is leaving toilet then how can I update my heap to incorporate those changes. 
Or Suggest if any other algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: I feel like a max heap isn't a great solution for this problem because every time someone enters or leaves a toilet, the "score" for a bunch of the toilets changes, so you have to rebuild the heap every time. Building a heap is O(nlogn), so even doing a simple linear search for the best toilet each time a new person arrives may be faster.

Comment: If there are 10 toilets, and number 1 and 10 are occupied, what should the output be?

Comment: dont know if there is a simpler solution but can be reduced to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-query-largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/ (largest continuous unoccupied range) where an occupied seat is -Infinite and unoccupied is 1

Comment: @ChatterOne if 1 and 10 are occupied solution is 11.

Comment: I really don't understand the solution being 11, care to explain?

Comment: @ChatterOne If there are 10 toilets. For first reservation request , assigned toilet  no is 1, for second reservation request assigned toilet no is 10 since 10th toilet is farthest from 1. Hence solution for two reservation on 10 toilet is 1+10 = 11.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. What I wanted to know is, if you have 10 toilets, and number 1 and 10 are occupied, what toilet will be allocated at the next request?

Comment: @ChatterOne if 1 and 10 are already allocated then distance of not occupied toilets array will look like this [0,1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,0] . Since two position 5th and 6th are at equal distance from nearest occupied toilet but according to rule 2, 5th one will be allocated next.